# separate groupby in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with groupby in pandas:

I have following df:

```
A     B          C          D
04547 2022-07-04 2022-07-04 1000000
04547 2022-07-11 2022-07-11 1000000
04547 2022-08-08 2022-08-08 1000000
04547 2022-10-11 2022-10-11 0100000
04547 2022-10-18 2022-10-18 0100000
04547 2022-10-24 2022-10-24 1000000
04547 2022-11-01 2022-11-01 0100000
04547 2022-11-08 2022-11-08 0100000
04548 2022-10-11 2022-10-11 0100000
04548 2022-10-18 2022-10-18 0100000
04548 2022-10-24 2022-10-24 1000000
04548 2022-11-01 2022-11-01 0100000
04548 2022-11-08 2022-11-08 0100000
```

my needed output should be:

```
    A           B           C        D
04547  2022-07-04  2022-08-08  1000000
04547  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
04547  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
04547  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
04548  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
04548  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
04548  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
```

but with:

```
a = {'A':'first','B':'first','C':'last','D':'first'}
df = df.groupby(['A','D']).agg(a)

A     B          C          D
4547 2022-10-11 2022-11-08  0100000
4547 2022-07-04 2022-10-24  1000000
4548 2022-10-11 2022-11-08  0100000
4548 2022-10-24 2022-10-24  1000000
```

because I have to interrupt grouping when a new series in column D starts seperated for each column A

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['D'].ne(df['D'].shift().cumsum()` as grouper the column D to ensure grouping by consecutive values ([`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) gives you access to the previous row value):

```
a = {'A':'first','B':'first','C':'last','D':'first'}
out = (df.groupby(['A', df['D'].ne(df['D'].shift()).cumsum()],
                  as_index=False)
         .agg(a)
      )
```

output:

```
       A           B           C        D
0  04547  2022-07-04  2022-08-08  1000000
1  04547  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
2  04547  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
3  04547  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
4  04548  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
5  04548  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
6  04548  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
```

Comment: @Glammy you're welcome (note that the two answers would not do the same thing, if you had non consecutive groups of A)

Comment: noted mozway ... at the end it seems to me your approach is the right one for me ;-) ... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If need groups by consecutive values of `A,D` columns use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed values comapre for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for `Series` and then add cumualtive sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
g = df[['A','D']].ne(df[['A','D']].shift()).any(1).cumsum()
a = {'A':'first','B':'first','C':'last','D':'first'}
df = df.groupby(g).agg(a)
print (df)
       A           B           C        D
1  04547  2022-07-04  2022-08-08  1000000
2  04547  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
3  04547  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
4  04547  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
5  04548  2022-10-11  2022-10-18  0100000
6  04548  2022-10-24  2022-10-24  1000000
7  04548  2022-11-01  2022-11-08  0100000
```